# How to get first and last date from MySQL table using EF in C#?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-6

This is my code to get the first date. It works, and I can show the date in dateTimepicker.

```
private void ShowButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String constring = "datasource=;port=3306;username=;password=";

    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(constring);

    int n = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
    testEntities dc = new testEntities(); 

    var getfirstDate = dc.table.Where(b => b.number == n).First();

    dateTimePicker1.Text =Convert.ToString (getfirstDate.date);
}
```

But, when I try to do the same with the last date

```
var getlastDate = dc.table.Where(b => b.number == n).Last();
```

an error message appears:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'project.table Lasttable' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`OrderByDescending()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534855(v=vs.110).aspx) + [`First()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535050(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var lastDate = table.Where(b => b.number == n)
     .OrderByDescending(b => b.Date)
     .First();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use ordering?

```
var getlastDate = dc.table.Where(b => b.number == n).OrderByDescending(b => b.Date).First();

//alternatively to using Where().First();

var getlastDate = dc.table.First(b => b.number == n).OrderByDescending(b => b.Date)
```

Comment: i need to show the last date  , my code works for the first date but show me error when i  use Last() !!

Comment: I know there is an error with last, that's why I have proposed these solutions - try out the first one

Comment: i tried both  your suggestions   , they work  well to get  first date and same error when i try  to replace First with Last in your code ! :(